# password confirm validation in angular - strange behaviour

Tags: angular, angular-validation

I implemented a confirm password validation in Angular with a custom validator. Here is the custom validator class:

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export class Validation {
  static match(controlName: string, checkControlName: string): ValidatorFn {
    return (controls: AbstractControl) => {
      const control = controls.get(controlName);
      const checkControl = controls.get(checkControlName);

      if (checkControl?.errors && !checkControl.errors.matching) {
        return null;
      }

      if (control?.value !== checkControl?.value) {
        controls?.get(checkControlName)?.setErrors({ matching: true });
        return { matching: true };
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

I use reactive form, this is how I build it up:

```
initSignupForm() {
    this.signupForm = new FormGroup(
      {
        email: new FormControl(this.formData.email, [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.email,
        ]),
        password: new FormControl(this.formData.password, [
          Validators.required,
        ]),
        passwordConfirm: new FormControl(this.formData.passwordConfirm, [
          Validators.required,
        ]),
      },
      { validators: [Validation.match('password', 'passwordConfirm')] }
    );
  }
```

And this is the component html:

```
<div class="card">
  <kendo-card width="320px">
    <h2>Regisztráció</h2>
    <form [formGroup]="signupForm">
      <kendo-formfield>
        <kendo-textbox placeholder="E-mail cím" formControlName="email">
          <ng-template kendoTextBoxPrefixTemplate>
            <kendo-svg-icon [icon]="icons.user"></kendo-svg-icon>
            <div id="empty-div"></div>
          </ng-template>
        </kendo-textbox>
        <kendo-formerror *ngIf="signupForm.controls.email.errors?.required"
          >Kötelező mező</kendo-formerror
        >
        <kendo-formerror *ngIf="signupForm.controls.email.errors?.email"
          >Hibás e-mail formátum</kendo-formerror
        >
      </kendo-formfield>
      <kendo-formfield>
        <kendo-textbox
          placeholder="Jelszó"
          #tbxPassword
          formControlName="password"
        >
          <ng-template kendoTextBoxPrefixTemplate>
            <button
              id="tbxPassword"
              kendoButton
              icon="eye"
              (click)="togglePass()"
            ></button>
          </ng-template>
        </kendo-textbox>
        <kendo-formerror>Kötelező mező</kendo-formerror>
      </kendo-formfield>
      <kendo-formfield>
        <kendo-textbox
          placeholder="Jelszó még egyszer"
          #tbxRepeatPassword
          formControlName="passwordConfirm"
        >
          <ng-template kendoTextBoxPrefixTemplate>
            <button kendoButton icon="eye" (click)="togglePassRep()"></button>
          </ng-template>
        </kendo-textbox>
        <kendo-formerror
          *ngIf="signupForm.controls.passwordConfirm.errors?.required"
          >Kötelező mező</kendo-formerror
        >
        <kendo-formerror *ngIf="signupForm.errors?.matching"
          >A két jelszó nem egyezik</kendo-formerror
        >
      </kendo-formfield>
      <button class="btn" kendoButton [primary]="true" (click)="submitForm()">
        ÚJ FIÓK LÉTREHOZÁSA
      </button>
      <div class="link">
        <span>Már van fiókod? </span>
        <a href="#" (click)="backToLogin()">Jelentkezz be</a>
      </div>
    </form>
  </kendo-card>
  <lang-selector></lang-selector>
</div>
```

It works, but with the following side effect. F. e. if I type 'a' in the password field and then 'b' in the confirm password field, I get the error message. Fine. Now, if I change 'b' to 'a', the error message is gone, form can be submitted. Fine. But if I change the first password ('a') to 'b', the error message disappears too, but the confirm password field remains red and I can't submit the form. The form itself has no more errors (I have checked it in the console), but the field itself has still this `matching` error. Why is this?

Comment: Does your problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here `Validation.match`

```
controls?.get(checkControlName)?.setErrors({ matching: true });
```

You are manually setting validation on `checkControlName`, but it should be on formGroup. Due to which somehow validation is mixing up and which is resulting in unexpected validation. I tried to figure out the scenario but did not able to find it.

To resolve your problem.

Remove `controls?.get(checkControlName)?.setErrors({ matching: true });` which is inside `if (control?.value !== checkControl?.value)`

Add below getter in component.ts: - To get FormGroup, so that we can use it in our template for validation.

```
get fg(): FormGroup {
    return this.signupForm as FormGroup;
}
```

Change

```
<kendo-formerror *ngIf="signupForm.errors?.matching">
    A két jelszó nem egyezik
</kendo-formerror>
```

To

```
<kendo-formerror *ngIf="fg.hasError('matching')">
    A két jelszó nem egyezik
</kendo-formerror>
```

That's it : [Similar Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11-form-validation-ytfwfy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I had a similar  thought also and commented this `controls?.get(checkControlName)?.setErrors({ matching: true });` out, as I was trying to track down the issue. But no success. It turned out, that I had to move out the `kendo-formerror` tag out of the `kendo-formfield` tag and now even with this code `signupForm.errors?.matching` I get the right behaviour. Thanks for your help and thanks also to @TotallyNewb.

Comment: It confused me using `matching` name, Since error was like `{ matching: true }` I think `{ notMatching : true }` will be more accurate.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I corrected it already.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're manually setting errors on your `passwordConfirm` control, but you're checking for errors on the form itself to display the error message. Since the value of `passwordConfirm` was not changed, the errors list was not cleared.

This means that the error will not be displayed (since you return null from your validator) but form is invalid (since there is still error on the `passwordConfirm`).

So, you either have to remove the line which sets the errors on the control itself (`controls?.get(checkControlName)?.setErrors({ matching: true });`), or ensure that on each evaluation of your validator you either add or remove the error to the array of existing errors.